# Table size and multirow problems

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I'm beginner and have some problems with a table. The table is to wide and I tried to solve it with multirows. But I don't get how to have the line break in the first column or if there is a easier way to get the table to fit.

```
 \documentclass[11pt, english, doublespacing,nolistspacing, parskip,]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l}
\toprule
\textbf{Equipment } & \textbf{Manufacturer} \\
\midrule
Camera C-Mount Adapter U TV0 5XC-3 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
\hline
Control Box Model Olympus BX-UCB & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Digital Microscope Camera DFC420 C} & Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar,\\
& Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Fluorescent Stereo Microscope M165 FC} & Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar,\\
& Germany \\
\hline
Gel Imaging System ChemiDoc XRS & Bio-Rad, Munich, Germany \\
\hline
Heating and Drying Table 13501 & Medax, Neum\"unster, Germany \\
\hline
Heating and Drying Table 14501 & Medax, Neum\"unster, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Heating Plate Magnetomix} & Colora Messtechnik, Lorch,\\
& Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Hybridization Oven Hybaid Shake'n'Stack} & Colora Messtechnik, Lorch,\\
& Germany \\
\hline
Ice Flaker Scotsman AF80 & Scotsman Ice Systems, Milan, Italy \\
\hline
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 150 & Hemel Brutger\"ate, Verl, Germany \\
\hline
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 600 & Hemel Brutger\"ate, Verl, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Infrared Heater IRB 1}& Edmund B\"uhler, Hechingen,\\& Germany \\
\hline
Integral Ultrapure Water Purification System Milli-Q  & Merck Millipore, Darmstadt, Germany \\
\hline
Magnetic Stirrer C-MAG MS 10 & IKA Werke, Stauffen, Germany \\
\hline
Microbalance MC21OP & Sartorius, G\"ottingen, Germany \\
\hline
Micropipette Puller & Bachofer, Reutlingen, Germany \\
\hline
Mikrotom & Leitz, Wetzlar, Germany \\
\hline
Open Heating Bath Circulator U3 & JULABO, Seelbach, Germany \\
\hline
Orbital Shaker GFL 3015 & GFL, Burgwedel, Germany\\
\hline
pH Meter Five Easy & Mettler-Toledo, Gie\ss{}en, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Pipetting Aid Pipetus}
& Hirschmann Laborger\"ate,\\&Eberstadt, Germany \\
\hline
Precision Balance SI-603 & Denver Instrument, G\"ottingen, Germany \\
\hline
Refrigerator & Liebherr, Ochsenhausen, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Shaker REAX2000}
 & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach,\\ & Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Steam Sterilizer Varioclav 2217}
 & HP Medizintechnik,\\& Oberschlei\ss{}heim, Germany \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Stereo Microscope Lighting KL 1500 LED} & Olympus, Hamburg,\\
& Germany \\
\hline
Sterilization Oven TV30-B & Memmert, Schwabach, Germany \\
\hline
Sterilization Oven WTC & Binder, Tuttlingen, Germany \\
\hline
Tabletop Centrifuge Biofuge 15  & Heraeus-Christ, Osterode, Germany \\
\hline
Ultrasonic Cleaner Elmasonic S10H & Elma Schmidbauer, Singen, Germany \\
\hline
Virtual Slide Microscope BX61VS & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
\hline
Vortexer Grant Bio PV-1 & Grant Instruments, Shepreth, UK \\
\hline
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Waving Platform Shaker Polymax 1040} & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach, \\
& Germany \\
\hline
Zoom Stereo Microscope Olympus SZX7 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I put it on the end of the document... Due to Stefan Pinnow, it's correct now! :-)

Comment: Why not use `p` columns or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `tabularx` environment, you really should also use the `X` column type. I suggest you not use *any* `\multirow` directives. And, instead of all those `\hline` directives, consider providing a bit more whitespace between the rows.

Something like the following, then:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % I don't have the file 'MastersDoctoralThesis.cls'
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % raggedright version of 'X' column type
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set text block margins
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}Y >{\hsize=0.85\hsize}Y @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Equipment } & \textbf{Manufacturer} \\
\midrule
Camera C-Mount Adapter U TV0 5XC-3 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Control Box Model Olympus BX-UCB & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Digital Microscope Camera DFC420 C &  Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Fluorescent Stereo Microscope M165 FC &  Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Gel Imaging System ChemiDoc XRS & Bio-Rad, Munich, Germany \\
Heating and Drying Table 13501 & Medax, Neumünster, Germany \\
Heating and Drying Table 14501 & Medax, Neumünster, Germany \\
Heating Plate Magnetomix &  Colora Messtechnik, Lorch, Germany \\
Hybridization Oven Hybaid Shake'n'Stack &  Colora Messtechnik, Lorch, Germany \\
Ice Flaker Scotsman AF80 & Scotsman Ice Systems, Milan, Italy \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 150 & Hemel Brutgeräte, Verl, Germany \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 600 & Hemel Brutgeräte, Verl, Germany \\
Infrared Heater IRB 1 & Edmund Bühler, Hechingen, Germany \\
Integral Ultrapure Water Purification System Milli-Q & Merck Millipore, Darmstadt, Germany \\
Magnetic Stirrer C-MAG MS 10 & IKA Werke, Stauffen, Germany \\
Microbalance MC21OP & Sartorius, Göttingen, Germany \\
Micropipette Puller & Bachofer, Reutlingen, Germany \\
Mikrotom & Leitz, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Open Heating Bath Circulator U3 & JULABO, Seelbach, Germany \\
Orbital Shaker GFL 3015 & GFL, Burgwedel, Germany\\
pH Meter Five Easy & Mettler-Toledo, Gießen, Germany \\
Pipetting Aid Pipetus &  Hirschmann Laborgeräte, Eberstadt, Germany \\
Precision Balance SI-603 & Denver Instrument, Göttingen, Germany \\
Refrigerator & Liebherr, Ochsenhausen, Germany \\
Shaker REAX2000 & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach, Germany \\
Steam Sterilizer Varioclav 2217 & HP Medizintechnik, Oberschleißheim, Germany \\
Stereo Microscope Lighting KL 1500 LED &  Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Sterilization Oven TV30-B & Memmert, Schwabach, Germany \\
Sterilization Oven WTC & Binder, Tuttlingen, Germany \\
Tabletop Centrifuge Biofuge 15  & Heraeus-Christ, Osterode, Germany \\
Ultrasonic Cleaner Elmasonic S10H & Elma Schmidbauer, Singen, Germany \\
Virtual Slide Microscope BX61VS & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Vortexer Grant Bio PV-1 & Grant Instruments, Shepreth, UK \\
Waving Platform Shaker Polymax 1040 &  Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach,  Germany \\
Zoom Stereo Microscope Olympus SZX7 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP mentioned the exact text block dimensions in a follow-up comment: To make the table fit on a page given the somewhat smaller smaller than initially assumed width of the text block, I would like to suggest you simply remove the "Germany" label, which occurs in 32 [!] of the 34 rows of the table. The names of the two other countries (Italy, United Kingdom) may be italicized to make them stand out a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % I don't have the file 'MastersDoctoralThesis.cls'
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % raggedright version of 'X' column type
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3cm, outer=2.5cm, bindingoffset=2cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}Y >{\hsize=0.85\hsize}Y @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Equipment } & \textbf{Manufacturer} \\
\midrule
Camera C-Mount Adapter U TV0 5XC-3 & Olympus, Hamburg \\
Control Box Model Olympus BX-UCB & Olympus, Hamburg \\
Digital Microscope Camera DFC420 C &  Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar \\
Fluorescent Stereo Microscope M165 FC &  Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar \\
Gel Imaging System ChemiDoc XRS & Bio-Rad, Munich \\
Heating and Drying Table 13501 & Medax, Neumünster \\
Heating and Drying Table 14501 & Medax, Neumünster \\
Heating Plate Magnetomix &  Colora Messtechnik, Lorch \\
Hybridization Oven Hybaid Shake'n'Stack &  Colora Messtechnik, Lorch \\
Ice Flaker Scotsman AF80 & Scotsman Ice Systems, Milan, \emph{Italy} \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 150 & Hemel Brutgeräte, Verl \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 600 & Hemel Brutgeräte, Verl \\
Infrared Heater IRB 1 & Edmund Bühler, Hechingen \\
Integral Ultrapure Water Purification System Milli-Q & Merck Millipore, Darmstadt \\
Magnetic Stirrer C-MAG MS 10 & IKA Werke, Stauffen \\
Microbalance MC21OP & Sartorius, Göttingen \\
Micropipette Puller & Bachofer, Reutlingen \\
Mikrotom & Leitz, Wetzlar \\
Open Heating Bath Circulator U3 & JULABO, Seelbach \\
Orbital Shaker GFL 3015 & GFL, Burgwedel\\
pH Meter Five Easy & Mettler-Toledo, Gießen \\
Pipetting Aid Pipetus &  Hirschmann Laborgeräte, Eberstadt \\
Precision Balance SI-603 & Denver Instrument, Göttingen \\
Refrigerator & Liebherr, Ochsenhausen \\
Shaker REAX2000 & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach \\
Steam Sterilizer Varioclav 2217 & HP Medizintechnik, Oberschleißheim \\
Stereo Microscope Lighting KL 1500 LED &  Olympus, Hamburg \\
Sterilization Oven TV30-B & Memmert, Schwabach \\
Sterilization Oven WTC & Binder, Tuttlingen \\
Tabletop Centrifuge Biofuge 15  & Heraeus-Christ, Osterode \\
Ultrasonic Cleaner Elmasonic S10H & Elma Schmidbauer, Singen \\
Virtual Slide Microscope BX61VS & Olympus, Hamburg \\
Vortexer Grant Bio PV-1 & Grant Instruments, Shepreth, \emph{United Kingdom} \\
Waving Platform Shaker Polymax 1040 &  Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach \\
Zoom Stereo Microscope Olympus SZX7 & Olympus, Hamburg \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textsc{Remark}: Country name mentioned in \emph{italics} if firm is not located in Germany.}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's nearly done! With my paper geometry, the table is too long for one page. Can I use {longtable} or {ltablex}?

Comment: \usepackage[a4paper,inner=3cm, outer=2.5cm, bindingoffset=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

Comment: @LarissaKluxen - Three (not mutually exclusive) suggestions to make the table fit on one page: (i) insert the instruction `\small` after `\begin{table}`, (ii) reduce the value of `\arraystretch` slightly, say to `1.1`, and (iii) delete all `, Germany` strings. Why the third option? All but two or three of the suppliers appear to be based in Germany -- mentioning all those "Germany" instances seems like it obscures more information than it provides.

Comment: @LarissaKluxen - I've posted an addendum to illustrate the look that results from implementing option (iii).

Comment: Yeah, thanks to all of you! It fits now and i included your suggestions! ;-)

Comment: @LarissaKluxen Your tye block is quite strange. Are you setting this up on purpose or are those strange values given by the template? If the latter,  you should reconsider your margin settings.

Comment: @Johannes_B it's a thesis and will be bound as a book. This is the reason for the broad left margin...

Comment: @LarissaKluxen Usually the left margin is smaller than the right. The bindingoffset gives the extra space for binding.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `ltablex`. I reduced linespacing inside the cells, as it didn't seem necessary:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, doublespacing,nolistspacing, parskip,]{report} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[a4paper,inner=3cm, outer=2.5cm, bindingoffset=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{2}{>{\raggedright\onehalfspacing\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Equipment } & \textbf{Manufacturer} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
(continued)\\
\toprule
\textbf{Equipment } & \textbf{Manufacturer} \\
\midrule
\endhead
%\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{ \raggedleft
 to be continued}
 \endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Camera C-Mount Adapter U TV0 5XC-3 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Control Box Model Olympus BX-UCB & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Digital Microscope Camera DFC420 C& Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Fluorescent Stereo Microscope M165 FC & Leica Microsystems, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Gel Imaging System ChemiDoc XRS & Bio-Rad, Munich, Germany \\
Heating and Drying Table 13501 & Medax, Neum\"unster, Germany \\
Heating and Drying Table 14501 & Medax, Neum\"unster, Germany \\
Heating Plate Magnetomix & Colora Messtechnik, Lorch, Germany \\
Hybridization Oven Hybaid Shake'n'Stack & Colora Messtechnik, Lorch, Germany \\
Ice Flaker Scotsman AF80 & Scotsman Ice Systems, Milan, Italy \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 150 & Hemel Brutger\"ate, Verl, Germany \\
Incubator Thermo de Luxe 600 & Hemel Brutger\"ate, Verl, Germany \\
Infrared Heater IRB 1& Edmund B\"uhler, Hechingen, Germany \\
Integral Ultrapure Water Purification System Milli-Q & Merck Millipore, Darmstadt, Germany \\
Magnetic Stirrer C-MAG MS 10 & IKA Werke, Stauffen, Germany \\
Microbalance MC21OP & Sartorius, G\"ottingen, Germany \\
Micropipette Puller & Bachofer, Reutlingen, Germany \\
Mikrotom & Leitz, Wetzlar, Germany \\
Open Heating Bath Circulator U3 & JULABO, Seelbach, Germany \\
Orbital Shaker GFL 3015 & GFL, Burgwedel, Germany\\
pH Meter Five Easy & Mettler-Toledo, Gie\ss{}en, Germany \\
Pipetting Aid Pipetus & Hirschmann Laborger\"ate, Eberstadt, Germany \\ Precision Balance SI-603 & Denver Instrument, G\"ottingen, Germany \\ Refrigerator & Liebherr, Ochsenhausen, Germany \\ %
Shaker REAX2000 & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach, Germany \\
Steam Sterilizer Varioclav 2217 & HP Medizintechnik, Oberschlei\ss{}heim, Germany \\
Stereo Microscope Lighting KL 1500 LED & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Sterilization Oven TV30-B & Memmert, Schwabach, Germany \\
Sterilization Oven WTC & Binder, Tuttlingen, Germany \\
Tabletop Centrifuge Biofuge 15 & Heraeus-Christ, Osterode, Germany \\
Ultrasonic Cleaner Elmasonic S10H & Elma Schmidbauer, Singen, Germany \\
Virtual Slide Microscope BX61VS & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany \\
Vortexer Grant Bio PV-1 & Grant Instruments, Shepreth, UK \\
Waving Platform Shaker Polymax 1040 & Heidolph Instruments, Schwabach, Germany \\
Zoom Stereo Microscope Olympus SZX7 & Olympus, Hamburg, Germany
 \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]